# Flags and deleted comment notifications not showing up next to posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css, moderation

With this new design, the notification box next to posts indicating flag history/comment deletion history no longer shows up.

<sub>Not sure the best way to screenshot something *not* showing up, but if anyone can grab a screenshot of what it *used to* look like (maybe from another beta site), that might be helpful.</sub>

Here's a screenshot from another beta site that shows the asterisk next to a moderated post:

---

[image: menu expanded]

Comment: Thanks, jmort. Exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed. The change will be on live server after our next production build.

Comment: I'm going to hijack your answer to ask something different about that indicator. :-)  I'm a mod on two other sites and I never see the box because it only appears at 1070px wide for the window.  My tablet only goes to 1024, and my (vertical) monitor to 1050.  If you could lower the threshold *just a bit more* for that, or help me out with custom CSS or a Greasemonkey script to mitigate, I'd be really grateful!  ([MSO request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188628/162102))

Comment: I'll work on this

Comment: Thanks very much!